# Create ascending numpy arrays that have different starting value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm sorry for not being able to word it well, I'm sure this has been asked before but I don't know what to search (I would appreciate it if you could let me know how to improve this question before downvoting). This is what I want:

```
array_1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
array_2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,0]
array_3 = [2,3,4,5,6,0,1]
...
array_7 = [6,0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

What is the fastest way to create this? The actual array length is around 700 or so.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this with `np.roll`:

```
for i in range(7):
    print(np.roll(np.arange(7, dtype=np.int), -i))

[0 1 2 3 4 5 6]
[1 2 3 4 5 6 0]
[2 3 4 5 6 0 1]
[3 4 5 6 0 1 2]
[4 5 6 0 1 2 3]
[5 6 0 1 2 3 4]
[6 0 1 2 3 4 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`scipy.linalg.circulant`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.circulant.html) with [`np.flip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html)

```
import scipy
a = np.flip(np.arange(7), 0)
# a: array([6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0])

b = scipy.linalg.circulant(a)
array([[6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

`b` is called a circulant matrix.

If you flip `b` again (return a view),

```
np.flip(b, 0)
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2],
       [4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3],
       [5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

Other ways to construct the matrix (credit to Paul Panzer):

```
linalg.toeplitz(np.arange(7)[::-1], (np.arange(7)-1) % 7)
linalg.hankel(np.arange(7), (np.arange(7)-1)%7)
```

**Reference**

Documentation of [`hankel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.hankel.html#scipy.linalg.hankel), [`toeplitz`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.toeplitz.html), and  [`circulant`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.circulant.html#scipy.linalg.circulant)

[Toeplitz and Circulant
Matrices: A review](http://ee.stanford.edu/~gray/toeplitz.pdf)

Thanks for @Paul Panzer's reminder on the shape of the matrix and various ways to generate the matrix.

Comment: @PaulPanzer thanks for the suggestion. I tried `linalg.toeplitz` but did not get similar to your solution. Yet, it will be like yours if you see from the bottom to the top. Sad that I cannot come up with a perfect solution to this.

Comment: @PaulPanzer thanks for the heap up. I tried to `flip` again to get close to your solution.

Comment: sorry you are right Toeplitz doesn't work I just didn't look at the result properly.

Comment: @PaulPanzer no no. I appreciate the message and really good to learn a new matrix.

Comment: Actually, `circulant` is a special case of `toeplitz`: `linalg.toeplitz(np.arange(7)[::-1], (np.arange(7)-1) % 7)`. What does work without any postprocessing is `linalg.hankel(np.arange(7), (np.arange(7)-1)%7)`

Comment: @PaulPanzer good to know it. I found some material talking about their connection!

Answer (score 2):

If a view is good enough then `stride_tricks` should be hard to beat, speed-wise (you could set `n` to a million and still get an instant result):

```
>>> n = 7
>>> a = np.arange(2*n-1)%n
>>> aa = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, (n, n), 2*a.strides)
>>> aa
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2],
       [4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3],
       [5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```